# How to create Singleton in ASP.NET Core host and explicitly call a method upon creation

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

**End goal:** Create the ability to run a background worker process in an ASP.NET Core application, but also inject a reference to that background worker in the ASP.NET Core DI container.  Let's say a background worker can be described as anything that implements:

```
    public interface IBackgroundWorker
    {
        void Start();
    }
```

I'm thinking it's best to have ASP.NET Core's DI container handle the actual creation of the worker process, which will be implemented as a Singleton.  That takes care of the creation and all the DI container part of the problem.  Luckily, this is pretty easy:

```
.ConfigureServices(serviceBuilder => serviceBuilder
  .AddSingleton<IBackgroundWorker>());
```

I can run this, however the object is not actually created until the first time it gets injected somewhere (like a Controller or something).  I want my background service to start running right away.  One approach I'm considering is using IApplicationBuilder to grab my service and start it:

```
.Configure(appBuilder =>
{
   IBackgroundWorker worker = appBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IBackgroundWorker>();
   worker.Start();
}
```

The actual implementation would do something a bit more complex, such as call `worker.Start();` in a new background thread, but that's fairly trivial.

My Question: Are there any flaws with this approach, or is there a better way of doing this?  I'm curious if a custom implementationFactory could be used in this scenario as well.  Any tips from the DI experts would be super appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered hosted service api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: They are automatically started by the framework as part of startup

Comment: Your current approach is recreating built-in features of the framework.

Comment: @Nkosi Cool, that looks like exactly what I'm trying to implement!  Probably should have did a bit more research to figure out if something like this already existed..

Comment: @Nkosi Looks like it _almost_ does what I want!  Unfortunately, it doesn't register the IHostedService as a singleton, so I can't reference it in my controllers.

Comment: You can register your worker as singleton and have it injected into a custom hosted service that starts the worker. That should cover the desired behavior

Comment: I am curious as to why the worker needs to be accessed by controllers. Sounds like a design issue (SRP violation)

Comment: I want to create healthcheck endpoints that can report status on the worker process, such as the number of items in the queue or last message processed, that sort of thing..  I'd rather use DI than have "static" properties or some such..  I'm open to better designs though..

Comment: @Nkosi I guess another way would be to inject some sort of "proxy" object as a Singleton shared by both the controllers and worker process.  This object could hold common information and be thread safe and all that.  Thinking about that more, this might be a better overall design.

Comment: Mediator pattern might fit this scenario

Comment: @Nkosi I think we're saying the same thing.  I wrote up a quick proof of concept and it appears to satisfy all my requirements.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding.